# AS3/AIR: Honeycomb/ICS systembar height. (need fullscreen resolution)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

On honeycomb tablets & ics phones there is this:
http://www.esato.com/gfx/news/img/android-honeycomb-system-bar_1297213454.jpg

And I don't seem to be able to get fullscreen resolution with any of these

stage.fullScreenHeight
Capabilities.screenResolutionY

Both return 1232px on my Asus tablet. I would need to be able to get 1280 and then 1280 - 1232 to get system bar's height which I need. Is there anyway to do this?

**EDIT: My fault! Capabilities.screenResolutionY & Capabilities.screenResolutionX works fine!**